# Flex Syntax Error

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am getting Syntax Error 1202 (Access of undefined property connection in package model) in the following code while trying to access the model.connection property. I don't see any reason why this would appear, can anyone see something I may be overlooking?

Model.as

```
package valueObjects
{
import flash.data.SQLConnection;

import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

public class Model
{
    public var connection:SQLConnection;
    public var albums:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    public var albumItems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    public var selectedAlbum:Number = 0;
    public var selectedItem:Number = 0;

    public function Model()
    {
    }
}
```

}

And the actual code in my default mxml file, init() is called on initialize

```
        import model.ModelLocator;

        import mx.core.mx_internal;

        import valueObjects.Model;

        protected var sqlConnection:SQLConnection;
        private var model:Model = new Model();

        protected function init():void
        {
            createDb();
            navigator.firstViewData = model;
        }

        protected function createDb():void
        {
            sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
            sqlConnection.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Oxford.db"));
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = 
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS albumItems (" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "album INTEGER, " + 
                "name STRING, " + 
                "dateAdded DATE)";
            stmt.execute();

            model.connection = sqlConnection;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show where the model is created in the default mxml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you have a package and a variable named 'model'.  When you try to access the variable named model, it thinks you are referring to the package.  If you correct this naming collision, you will see that this issue is fixed.

Comment: I think I have run into this issue before, you would think I would learn! Thanks so much!